# Standard deviation on a random generated sequence

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

First i don't know the correct terms for math in English so please be patient with me.

I have a pseudo-random generated sequence of numbers (from 0.00 to 99.99), I have access to the parameters used to create the sequence so I could get any of the numbers if I wanted to. The seeds are changed on a specific time and cannot be consulted while they are in use, that means we can only check the latest completed run and cannot infer the results of the current run.

That being said I need to calculate the probability of a given sequence of numbers are all lower than X, I'm calculating like this: $(e)^{c}$ where $e$ is the probability of a number is lower then expected and $c$ is the length of that sequence, example: numbers lower then 10.00, that means 10% of them will be lower, by my calculations a sequence of 3 numbers all lower then 10.00 have a chance of 0.1% of happening, but in the real tests this probability reach 0.3% in a set of 1000000 numbers.

How could i calculate this approximate variation?

I need a very precise number because we are dealing with bad sequences near 50 numbers long and without the standard deviation that could cause a big problem

Comment: We do the experiment $3$ times, record success if we get $3$ in a row under $10$. Repeat this experiment $n$ times, and look at the *number* of successes. This has variance close to $n(1/10)(9/10)$. The *proportion* of successes has variance $(1/10)(9/10)/n$. If I understand your simulation results right, a proportion of $0.3\%$ with $n=10^6$ basically can't happen.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand what you said. When something happens all the time, the deviation is very low, but when it happens less frequently it causes a big deviation, this is what I am trying to calculate, or at least aproximate

Comment: OK, I will rephrase. If your pseudo-random number generator is a good one. then if you generate $3$ numbers $1000000$ times, the probability that about $3000$ of the sequences (that is $0.3\%$ of them) will have all three members less than $10$ is virtually $0$. Conclusion: the generator is (almost certainly) flawed.

Comment: I get it now, but we do not generate one small sequence every time, we pick 1000000 numbers and inside this sequence we check the biggest chain where all the numbers are lower than expected

Comment: If we have $6$ in a row less than $10$, does that count as $4$ length $3$ chunks?

Comment: No, if a sequence is greater then 3 it is detected as 3